# Nuxtjs/Firebase permission denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nuxt.js, firebase-security

Can't read/retrieve data from firebase realtime database using nuxt-community's firebase module link [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module). Already added my firebase config inside `nuxt.config.js` file like below.

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    [
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
          authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
          databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
          projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
          storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
          messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
          appId: process.env.APP_ID,
          measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
          databaseSecret: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET,
        },
        services: {
          auth: true,
          realtimeDb: true,
        }
      }
    ],
  ],
```

**Rules:** I'm not sure if this is correct. I just want to restrict read access to only me.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === 'my-uid-here'",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

**SomeComponent.vue**

```
async loadFromDb() {
      const messageRef = this.$fireDb.ref('cases')
      try {
        const snapshot = await messageRef.once('value')
        alert(snapshot.val().cases)
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
        return
      }
},
```

Comment: The simple explanation is below. If you want to secure it better, I highly recommend studying https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security and https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read from `/cases`, while your security rules only grant read access to `/users`. If you want to read `/cases` (too), you'll have to grant read access to `/cases` (too).

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "false"
      }
    },
    "cases": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```